# JS function doesn't work in a window

Tags: javascript

I open a new window and I need to call a function on it.
If I write in the new window the funcion inside $(document).ready it works, but I would like to call it as a "normal" function...
My code:

```
var mywindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=800');
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>My Title</title>');
mywindow.document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>');    
mywindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>');
mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
mywindow.document.write(data);
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
mywindow.document.close();   
mywindow.myFunction();
```

I get "mywindow.myFunction is not a function"

Writing the function on  works...

`mywindow.document.write('<script> $(document).ready(myFunction())</script>')`

why? What's wrong when I call the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mywindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=800');
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>My Title</title>');
mywindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="full host and path to js"></script>'); // see 1.
mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
mywindow.document.close();  

mywindow.addEventListener('load', function() { // see 2.
    mywindow.myFunction();
});
```

1. the src for javascript needs to be fully qualified - e.g. http://example.com/path/file.js
2. you must`mywindow.document.close();` to trigger the load event, then and
   only then will the function be available